# Is it possible to simply talk to a specific port on my google cloud server?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to set up a google server to host requests for a simple turn based game.
I was hoping to be able to just type in a google generated URL and append the port my server is set to listen on and have it routed to my google cloud server.
Is this realistic or am I oversimplifying the use of Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: i believe you're looking for something similar to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmjqPpQdtW8

Comment: Are you referring to Compute Engine?

Comment: Which service are you using? What is the port number? Do you have your own domain? Edit your question and provide more details.

Comment: Which GCP product do you use?

Comment: Do you have one or several servers in parallel?